# Identify 12V connector

Tags: connector, identification

Can anybody identify this connector? The inside diameter is about 5mm and there is a thread around the outside. I need to get the opposite connector to plug it into.
[image]

Comment: Where does it come from? What is it used for? Some more information might help.

Comment: It's an inline barrel connector. There are lots out there, with a plethora of different sizes for the various diameters for both the hole and the pin (if any) which is in the hole. I doubt we can help much more than that.

Comment: @puff That and a picture reference would be an answer.

Comment: When you say "about 5 mm," could that be 6.25 mm? Do you have a 1/4" headphone plug you could try in it?

Answer (score 1):

It's an inline barrel connector. There are lots out there, with a plethora of different sizes for the various diameters for both the hole and the pin (if any) which is in the hole. I doubt we can help much more than that.

There's a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector) entry for them, they are that common.

If you need to get something which mates with this one, and you can't find a datasheet or formal description, you options are either to try and measure it accurately, or trial and error with a bunch of similar looking connectors.

Don't forget, the internal pin length and girth vary along with the diameter and length of the main orifice.

Comment: Option 3: cut it off and use something else.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was thinking of doing that but then how do you differentiate positive and negative.

Comment: @user1897830 a continuity test will confirm that. (Usually outer diameter is negative, inner pin is positive, always check though)

Comment: @Puffafish I scraped away some of the insulation on one of the wires leading from the connector and did a continuity test between the uninsulated wire and both terminals. I never got a beep on either the inner pin or outer sleeve. What is going on?

Comment: @user1897830 If you don't know which is +ve and -ve, having the physically matching plug won't help either. What equipment is it connected to? Can you open the equipment to try to find out the polarity?

Comment: @user1897830 Its connected to a small dc/ac converter/transformer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Its connected to a small dc/ac converter/transformer. Not possible to open it.

Comment: @user1897830 What equipment will be plugged into it? Sometimes there is a symbol showing if it needs to be wired for centre-positive or for centre-negative.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's centre positive. But if the connector is cut off there is no way of knowing which wire is which.

Comment: @user1897830 If you had a multimeter, you cut find out which is which. If you found braided wire when you scraped away the insulation then there might be two more wires inside that.